# Blank screen that does not accept any input, while trying to intall Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, grub2

While trying to install Ubuntu over my Windows partition, I encountered an exception and had to restart the system.

Since then, when the system starts, it boots to a blank screen with the cursor blinking. It does not accept any key press, including the F8/F12 keys.

I suspect its because of a corrupted GRUB Boot Loader. Can anyone kindly suggest what do I do to resolve this.

Comment: since you are installing  it anyway .. have you attempted to just  install it again?

Comment: I am unable to move beyond the boot blank screen to install it again.

Comment: well to install you need a bootable USB or DVD/CD and you would have to set bios to boot to the removable device as the first device so it boots to that instead of the hard drive. What did you use to first install Ubuntu?

Comment: I was using Wubi to install, when it happened.

Comment: ahh .. well you seem to have access to another computer can you download Ubuntu and burn it to a DVD? or if  you don't have a DVD drive in the corrupted PC, you can create a bootable USB instead... if the system you are using now is windows Rufus is a good program to create a bootable USB with Ubuntu

Comment: Was able to recover from this using a bootable USB, and setting the bios to boot to the device.  Thanks for the help :)

Comment: no problem, glad you were able to get it to work :D

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it may not be the problem about grub, and I have met similar problem before. In fact,according to your description, it may be the graphic driver problem, especially when you have Nvidia driver. So just try [reinstall the graphic driver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia).

If you are sure it is the grub problem, try to reconfigure it.

- Reboot and hold SHIFT Key, and the grub boot menu should appear.
- Select `Advanced Options for Ubuntu` and enter recovery mode
- open a shell and mount the root disk, update grub:

  `sudo update-grub`

More details about ubuntu grub from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2).